# Empathy refusing to connect

Tags: 12.04, empathy

I have configured Empathy with Facebook and Gmail just after installing Ubuntu 12.04. It worked flawlessly for few days and one fine day it crashed. After that when ever I am opening Empathy it is failing to connect to Gmail and Facebook ( I have not checked any other IM services).
After the crash I removed my account configurations and added once again but still facing the same issue.

Any pointer to fix issue is appreciable.

[image]

Comment: could you access both these accounts from a browser?

Comment: @beeju, Yes, I am able to access my accounts from browser.

Comment: @Abhijeet Have you tried to reinstall Empathy? You can do this by running this command in your terminal: `sudo apt-get purge empathy && sudo apt-get install empathy`

Comment: @BasharatSial, Tried your step. Still same issue.

Comment: Have you tried uninstalling both empathy and telepathy at the same time? Empathy communicates with Telepathy which does the actual work of communicating with online services. If you run empathy from a terminal do you get any error messages?

Comment: @John, Can you specify the package name. I am not able to find it. I have also raised a bug for it.

Comment: You might try reinstalling telepathy-gabble, telepathy-haze, telepathy-salut, and telepathy-mission-control-5. You can see the telepathy related software in ubuntu-software-center by clicking on `Installed`, clicking on the technical items link on the bottom, and type telepathy in the search bar.

Answer (score -1):

The reasoning is you're trying to use your log in e-mail address. It requires you to use your assigned name. The quickest way to find this information out is to login to Facebook via a web browser and check out your own profile. It should the web url as facebook . com / YOURNAMEHERE.

Use that given name and your password you used to log in and it should work.

Comment: Please check the info. I am able to login to Gmail and suddenly it stopped working.

Comment: You might want to double-check. When I first set it up, I tried using my login e-mail address and received the same error. After further inspection is when I realized that the login wasn't the same as when you login to facebook.com

Read the following closely.
![Read closely](http://oi47.tinypic.com/2mpev54.jpg)