# Workaround to make empathy to connect to google talk

Tags: 15.10, empathy, google-talk

[These](https://askubuntu.com/questions/548143/empathy-accounts-require-authorization) two [questions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/135543/empathy-refusing-to-connect) are the same, but they are from older Ubuntu releases. Some have proposed that deleting and re-adding the account works, but this is definitly overkill. [This bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/empathy/+bug/1168582) documents a faster workaround the issue, that involves killing the `signonpluginprocess` process, which forces

Is there a simpler way (for newbies) of nudging empathy to connect to Google Talk, without resorting to the `kill` command?

Answer (score 0):

As it turns out, I think I found a simpler way of doing this, without opening a terminal, or hitting <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>F2</kbd> and pasting the `killall -6 signonpluginprocess` command.

When you see the following error:

[image]

... you know you've hit the bug. Apparently, when you open the `Online Accounts`, it automatically figures it out, and corrects the connection/authentication issue.

Press the blue curved arrow to retry connecting and then press <kbd>F4</kbd> to open `Online Accounts`. It should be enough for empathy

P.S.: this is not a fix for the bug, just another workaround for the issue. I wish I knew why it works, though.

P.S.2: I haven't tested this on other networks (Facebook, ICQ, etc) since I don't use them.